# Angular jamsine test spyOn not intercepting call

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to test my Angular controller. I am trying to mock out the loginService->loginStatus service call the controller makes using jasmine's spyOn. Even though I am setting the return value I want the service call to return, when I run the test I am receiving this response:

> Unexpected request: POST api/users/loginStatus

It is still calling the real LoginService call which is this:

```
loginStatus: function () {
                   return $http.post('api/users/loginStatus');  
             }
```

My test is setup as below:

```
describe('Logging in', function()
{
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('corpusRoom'));

    var ctrl, $scope, mockHttp, room, roomStateService;

    beforeEach(function () {
        room = 'mockRoom';
        uid = 'fakeuid';
        roomStateService =
            {
                roomName: function () {
                    return 'fakeRoom';
                }
            }

        angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('room', room);
            $provide.value('uid', uid);
            $provide.value('RoomStateService', roomStateService);
        });
    });

    describe('Login controller', function () {

        var loginService, $q;

        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _$route_, LoginService, _$q_, $httpBackend, RoomStateService)
        {
            $q = _$q_
            loginService = LoginService;
            roomStateService = RoomStateService;
            mockHttp = $httpBackend;
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            mockHttp.whenGET('app/room/room.html').respond(200);
            mockHttp.whenGET('app/other/notFound.html').respond(200);
            ctrl = $controller('LoginController', {
                LoginService: loginService,
                RoomStateService: roomStateService
            });
        }));

        it('should log out the user if already logged in', function (done) {
            var deferredLoginStatus = $q.defer();
            spyOn(loginService, 'loginStatus').and.returnValue(deferredLoginStatus);
            spyOn(loginService, 'logout');
            deferredLoginStatus.resolve({ isLoggedIn: true});
            $scope.$apply();
            expect(loginService.logout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            done();
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: You're not calling any $scope or ctrl method in your test. So I assume that the logout happens when the controller is created. But when you create the controller (using `ctrl = $controller('LoginController' ...`), you have not spied on the service yet.Move what you want to test, i.e. the controller creation, inside the `it()`, after you have spied on the service that the controller is supposed to call.

Comment: Thank, you are right, the call happens when the controller is created. Could you tell me how I inject $controller into the it()?

Comment: You can store it in a variable the same way you're already saving loginService and $q. or you can use `it('should ...', inject(function($controller) { ... }));`

Comment: Great, that works if I comment out the controller creation in the beforeEach and create it in the It() after my spies are set up, otherwise I get the same error. Only way i can think of to fix it is to create the controller specifically in each test and move it out the beforeEach, although it doesn't feel right?

Comment: You can still use a different describe() with its beforeEach mocking everything needed and creating the controller, for the tests that don't test the controller creation. Or you could use components, which have an init() hook function called by Angular automatically, where you would put this initialization logic. That would make it simpler to create a controller for tests which don't care about this initialization logic.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I created a separate describe('Login controller initialization') which made total sense after you said it. Im new to Angular, so not sure what you mean about using components. I thought this was the new way to create directives, so not sure how it fits to this case. Would love to read up on it though so I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

change your spyOn to:

```
spyOn(loginService, 'loginStatus').and.returnValue(deferredLoginStatus.promise);
```

And
add  the following line in your beforeEach `mockHttp.whenPOST('api/users/loginStatus').respond({ isLoggedIn: true});`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that earlier and it does work but I guessed it probably wasn't the best way to do it as then I am relying on how the internals of LoginService are implemented when really I shouldn't care, I just want to mock the call.